# NotEnoughReplicasException: The size of the current ISR Set(2) is insufficient to satisfy the min.isr requirement of 3

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I had the following setup
Brokers : 3 - all are up and running with min.insync.replicas=3.

I created a topic with the following configuration

> bin\windows\kafka-topics --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --topic
> topic-ack-all --create --partitions 4 --replication-factor 3

I triggered the producer with "ack = all" and producer is able to send the message.
However, the problem starts when i start the consumer

> bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9094,localhost:9092 --topic topic-ack-all --from-beginning

The error is

> NotEnoughReplicasException: The size of the current ISR Set(2) is
> insufficient to satisfy the min.isr requirement of 3
> NotEnoughReplicasException:The size of the
> current ISR Set(3) is insufficient to satisfy the min.isr requirement
> of 3 for partition __con

I see two kinds of errors here . I went though the documentation and had also understaning about "min.isr", However, these error messages are not clear .

1. What does it mean by current ISR set ? Is it different for each topic and what it signifies ?
2. I guess min.isr is same as min.insync.replicas . I hope is should have value at least same as "replication factor" ?

**Update #1**

```
Topic: topic-ack-all    PartitionCount: 4       ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs:            
        Topic: topic-ack-all    Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1,2,3  
        Topic: topic-ack-all    Partition: 1    Leader: 1       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 1,2,3  
        Topic: topic-ack-all    Partition: 2    Leader: 1       Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 1,2,3  
        Topic: topic-ack-all    Partition: 3    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,3,2 Isr: 1,2,3
```

**Update 2**

```
Topic: __consumer_offsets       PartitionCount: 50      ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: compression.type=producer,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=104857600
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 1    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 2    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 3    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 4    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 5    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 6    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 7    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 8    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 9    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 10   Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 11   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 12   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 13   Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 14   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 15   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 16   Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 17   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 18   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 19   Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 20   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 21   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 22   Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 23   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 24   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 25   Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 26   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 27   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 28   Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 29   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 30   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 31   Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 32   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 33   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 34   Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 35   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 36   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 37   Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 38   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 39   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 40   Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 41   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 42   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 43   Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 44   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 45   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 46   Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 47   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 48   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 49   Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `bin\windows\kafka-topics --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --describe`?

Comment: @MickaelMaison, just added. Thanks

Comment: and also, what is the reason "Configs" flag shows some status sometimes and no status other times ?

Comment: The error is with the `__consumer_offsets` topic when you run the consume. Can you add the description of that topic too?

Comment: @MickaelMaison I just added, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the output you pasted, it looks like the `__consumer_offsets` topic was created with a single replica.

It also looks like your broker are setup with `min.insync.replicas` = 3.

With this configuration, it's expected to get `NotEnoughReplicasException` if a consumer commits offsets.

The `__consumer_offsets` topic is created automatically when the first consumer connect to the cluster. One common way to end up in your situation is if you ran a consumer while you only had a single broker running. In that case the `__consumer_offsets` would be created with a single replica.

Assuming it's a dev environment, the easiest way to get back to a valid state is to delete the `__consumer_offsets` and rerun your consumer while all 3 brokers.are up.

Comment: Please let me acknowledge the assumptions were exactly correct. Few follow up questions . For "min.insync.replicas" with value of 3 , I assume we need at least 3 (or 4) brokers ?  What does it mean by current ISR set ? Is it different for each topic and what it signifies ? Why do you think it gave this complaint - NotEnoughReplicasException:The size of the current ISR Set(3) is insufficient to satisfy the min.isr requirement of 3 for partition __con . The error looks like happening because ISR set should be greater than min.isr , so in this case - 4 brokers needed ?

Comment: Few more questions - so, "min.insync.replicas" should be agreed upon before creating the cluster not to have these chaos ? If not , this may need to be changed per topic in production ?

Comment: And also, can "min.insync.replicas" be same as "Replication factor" ?

Comment: That's a lot of questions! You usually want the number of replicas (replication factor) to be larger than min.insync.replicas. This allows to perform a rolling restart of brokers and keep everything working. 3 replicas and 2 min.insync is a very common configuration bbut if you need 3 min.insync then you'll need at least 4 replicas.
All of these settings can be changed (even at runtime) and you can always add overrides to topics. For a prod environment, you obviously want to make decisions in advance but for dev you can change config as needed.

Comment: Thanks Mickael, that gave enough insights . I am wondering the reason why it failed in the above case, could be the reason there are not those many brokers (4) as specified in min.insync.replica (3) . I will update the config for "__consumer_offsets__" to be 2 to see if it works

Comment: I updated the config for "consumer_offsets" to be 1 (as that is the orinigal value, it works fine now )  PS C:\confluent-5.5.0> bin\windows\kafka-configs --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name __consumer_offsets --add-config min.insync.replicas=1 --alter